# Entanglement entropy for finite interval using heat kernel method

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am looking for some reference for calculation of entanglement entropy(EE) for a finite interval in 4 spacetime dimensions using heat kernel method. Till now I have only found references where the calculation has been done for a halfspace. The paper by Wilczek http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0993v2 says that the heat kernel method works well only when the region of interest is a half space. So can anyone please let me know whether the heat kernel method is suited for finite size interval calculations of EE or suggest a reference for the same?

Thanks in advance.